# Run npm script on termination from console "CTRL+C"

Tags: npm-scripts, concurrently

I want to run `yarn dev` to start pm2 and webpack in watch mode for development. Problem is that I need to kill pm2 instance (run `yarn pm2:del`) when I terminate manually pressing "CTRL+C". How can it be done?

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn pm2:del && yarn pm2:dev && yarn wp:dev",
    "pm2:dev": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only dev",
    "pm2:del": "pm2 delete all || exit 0",
    "wp:dev": "webpack --mode=development --watch"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some research and found this: [how to close server on ctrl+c when in no-daemon](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2833#issuecomment-298560152)

```sh
pm2 kill && pm2 start ecosystem.json --only dev --no-daemon
```

It works if you run pm2 alone but you are running 2 programs together, so give it a try below script:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "yarn pm2:del && yarn pm2:dev && yarn wp:dev && yarn pm2:del"
    }
}
```

**How does it work?**

- first, kill all pm2 daemons
- start a pm2 daemon
- start webpack
- finally, kill all pm2 daemons again, it will run when you press `CTRL + C`

Comment: it didn't run last step on exit to kill pm2 :(

Comment: Interesting, I tried this, and worked. I used this script for test: `echo 'foo' && node && echo 'bar'`. First `echo 'foo'` worked then the node interactive shell opened finally `echo 'bar'` worked when I pressed `CTRL + C` :/

Comment: When I pressed `CTRL + C`, Node exit with 0. I think Webpack doesn't use 0 when exit, probably the next code was not executed because of this.

Comment: with command like this `"yarn pm2:del && echo '1' && yarn pm2:dev && echo '2' && yarn wp:dev && echo '3' && yarn pm2:del && echo '4'"` i get log 4/1/2

Comment: Can you try `"yarn pm2:del && yarn pm2:dev && yarn wp:dev && yarn pm2:del"` again? After hit  `CTRL + C`  and run `echo $?` to see last command exit code

Comment: it dont run anything after webpack

Comment: I mean after `CTRL +C` in console manually

Comment: it's empty line

Comment: after I moved command in exact order to .sh script - it worked :/

Comment: I'm glad it worked, my brain burned here :D

Comment: I see what's going on here... Webpack exits with code 130 instead of code 0 when you press `CTRL + C`, so the next code is never executed. This is not a valid thing for script files, so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've created `dev.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
yarn pm2:del
yarn pm2:dev
yarn wp:dev
yarn pm2:del
```

And run it using `yarn dev`:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "sh ./scripts/dev.sh",
    "pm2:dev": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only dev",
    "pm2:del": "pm2 delete all || exit 0",
    "wp:dev": "webpack --mode=development --watch"
  }
```